# Can "at" be used with "reach"?

Tags: prepositions

My friend says that "at" could be used with "reach" 
e.g. "i couldn't reach at the airport"
but I don't think that's possible because "reach" is a transitive verb which doesn't require preposition
so, what do you think? could "at" be used with "reach" or not?

Comment: What is the intended meaning of the sentence? "They could not reach at _what_ at the airport"? This sentence is confusing to me, and does not seem correctly formed with this combination of _at_ and _reach_.

Comment: Unfortunately a comment was deleted by the migration. Fumblefingers commented; "the construction to reach at usually means to attempt to reach out and grasp. It's usually "literal" in that it's rarely used particularly figuratively (mostly it's limited to being something you can do with your outstretched arm)"

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. It also occurs to me that *to reach at = to stretch towards* also occurs as *to reach **for***.

Answer (score 1):

"Reach" has several meanings, primarily:

> [**reach**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reach) (v):
>
> 1. (with adverb of direction) Stretch out an arm in a specified direction in order to touch or grasp something.  *Leith reached for the nearest folder*
> 2. (with object) Arrive at; get as far as. *"Goodbye," she said as they reached the door*

Neither of these commonly uses "at".  You *reach for* something, or you simply *reach something*, but you would not *reach at* the airport -- *unless* you were describing reaching for something while *at* the airport.

> I **reached** for my luggage **at** the airport, but found it had been stolen.

This sentence is *odd* but grammatical.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the ***at*** is sort-of included in the meaning of ***reach*** (your second sense) so adding it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

**To reach a person at some place**=to get in touch with them, by telephone or message.

**To reach a place**=to arrive at a place in the sense of have enough gas in your car. To manage to get to a place.

I was not able to reach the airport [no gas].
I was not able to reach Susie at the airport [talk to her on the phone]

Comment: "If you have any questions, you can reach at james@mail.com", "Please reach at annie@abc.com to get a custom quote". Does these sentences look grammatically correct to you @Lambie

Comment: @0aslam0 That is incorrect. It 's: You can reach **me** at james@mail.com" //reach a person [me, him, her, us] at y.